# Lubuntu vs. Ubuntu Installation

Tags: system-installation

So all I'm wondering is if the installation methods for Lubuntu and Ubuntu are the same or if they're different from each other, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lubuntu is based off of Ubuntu, so the core of the OS is the same. Like Xen said, the major difference between the two is that they have different [Desktop Environments](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Desktop_environment).

The installer, unless you're using the MinimalCD image (which uses a text-based, ncurses UI and downloads the system files instead of storing them on the installer) is essentially the exact same as the default Ubuntu installer - just branded differently.

Thus, since the core of the OS is the same, unless you configure it manually the installers will install the OS in the same way other than the included software.

Answer (score 2):

They just use & install different desktops, Lubuntu uses LXDE, Ubuntu uses Unity (last I'd read) and some different default programs are installed, but can install & run the same programs.

They both use the same installer & methods.